# Conectar a BBDD con singleton o gobal?

Tags: java, jdbc, singleton

Estoy creando una aplicacion en Java que se conecta a MySQL. El método bajo un patrón singleton para conectarme a la base de datos es el siguiente:

```
public static Connection getInstance(){

        if(connection == null){
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");//"com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USUARIO, CONTRASENA);
            } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                ClaseAccesoria.errorAlert("ERROR", "ERROR en Connetion","ERROR en Connetion: "+e.getMessage()  );
            }
        }
        return connection;
    }
```

En cada método de la aplicación que necesito acceder a la base de datos cierro la la conexión, esperando que la volviera a abrir llamando al método de arriba. Sin embargo, no ocurre como esperaba, una vez que el primer método cierra la conexión con close(), cuando quiero acceder de nuevo me salta un mensaje: No operations allowed after connection closed.
Sería mejor usar una conexión no singleton, multiinstancia si mi aplicación está constantemente accediendo a una base de datos??? O debería cerrar la conexión al salir de la app?

Pego abajo un metodo con el que accedo a la base de datos:

```
 @Override
    public List<Usuario> listar() {

        List<Usuario> listaUsuarios = new ArrayList<>();

        Connection connection=null;

        Statement queryUsuariosApp= null;

        try {
            connection = ConectarBD.getInstance();

            queryUsuariosApp = connection.createStatement();

            ResultSet rs = queryUsuariosApp.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM `usuario`");

            while(rs.next()){
                listaUsuarios.add(new Usuario(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3),rs.getString(4)));
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            ClaseAccesoria.errorAlert("ERROR","Error en ManejaProducto.listar", "Message: "+e.getMessage());
        }finally {
            try {
                queryUsuariosApp.close();
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                ClaseAccesoria.errorAlert("ERROR", "SQLException", "Message: " + ex.getMessage());
            }

        }

        return listaUsuarios;
    }
```

Comment: Lamentablemente tu pregunta está basada en opiniones. A esto: *Sería mejor usar una conexión no singleton, multiinstancia si mi aplicación está constantemente accediendo a una base de datos? O debería cerrar la conexión al salir de la app?* Unos te responderán que lo primero, otros que lo segundo, otros que ni lo primero ni lo segundo, otros que cualquiera de los dos dependiendo de tu contexto, de la naturaleza de tu aplicación etc, etc, etc. Puedes tener miles de respuestas. En SO las preguntas deben atenerse a un problema específico. Por cierto, desde JDBC 4, no es necesario `Class.forName`

Comment: Depende… ¿La aplicación es cliente/servidor o multi-capa? ¿Es web, red local o mono-usuario, etc.?

Comment: Vale. Me doy cuenta que mi pregunta no puede plantearse de la manera que lo he hecho. Si hay una cuestión concreta que os agradecería si me pudieseis aclarar. Mi caso es una aplicación de escritorio en una conexión local a una base de datos. Creo que usaré una conexion multiistancia en la que tras acceder a la base de datos para hacer una operación cierro la conexion. Con una conexión singleton me obliga a mantener la conexión abierta durante toda la sesión, y creo que eso podría acarrearme algún problema. No estoy seguro.

Comment: Los problemas que tendrías serían los que tú mismo puedas provocar -y corregir-. Es el caso más simple, y una conexión global que se abra al iniciar y se cierre junto con la app es suficiente. El singleton no es necesario aunque tampoco hace daño.